# how to use Purrr/reduce combine dataframe objects

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

There are data.frame objects in R environment named as `'data_1\data_2\....data_20'`,
`reduce(objects,rbind)` failed ,anyone can help ? Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
for (i in c(1:20)){
  assign(paste0('data_',i),data.frame(category=c('a','b'),sales=c(1,2)))
}

objects <- ls(pattern='data') %>%  as.list() 
data_total <- reduce(objects,rbind)
```

below code can work,but have to input `data_1\data_2\....data_20` as parmeter

```
data_total <- reduce(list(data_1,data_2),rbind)
```

Comment: You don't need `reduce()`.  `rbind()` (or `bind_rows()`) can be used with lists. `do.call(rbind, mget(unlist(objects)))`  (or `dplyr::bind_rows(mget(unlist(objects)))`).  In general you should avoid cluttering the global environment and make sure you are returning a list of objects instead of 'loose' objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data_frames <- str_c("data_", 1:20)

map_dfr(data_frames, get)
```